# Is there a way to convert MTG creatures and characters to AD&D?

Tags: monsters, npc, adnd-1e, conversion

There are a lot of creatures and characters from the trading card game *Magic: The Gathering* that I would like to incorporate into my *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons* campaigns. Specifically, I'm looking for how to convert from Magic's Attack/Defense to D&D's AC/HP or specific DAM. Is there a published process for such a conversion?

If not, is there a tested homebrew conversion process that a user is willing to share?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. As of this writing, four users (none of them me) have voted to close this question as lacking focus. I suspect those users want the question to ask about just one character or monster. Nonetheless, I hope it's okay that I edited this question in an effort to keep it open and within the site's guidelines. (The site doesn't like questions that are actually just open-ended requests for suggestions, for instance; those work better on a forum.) No matter what though, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Hi Marcus, your original question was closed as it was too broad for us to be able to give a good answer to. *"How to encorperate MtG into D&D?"* is quite a large topic. However it seems your main question is actually how to convert monster stats between the games. That is an answerable question. If you focus the question on what you are trying to achieve and perhaps add an example for context, it should get reopened shortly. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: @linksassin The original question specifically asked about converting MtG creature stats into AD&D creature stats. Should it be rolled back to the older revision?

Comment: @MikeQ The original question was titled *What's the best way to incorporate MTG into AD&D?* but the body asked only about converting monsters and NPCs stats from *MTG* to *AD&D*. I think the question's current title is fine as the asker didn't seem interested in, for example, converting *MTG*'s magic system, instants and socereries, or artifacts from to *AD&D*. (Certainly the asker *can* expand the question's mandate, but it'll surely remain closed if the asker does!)